# gzip compression tool usage

Tags: javascript, gzip

I just got the GZip software from this site http://www.gzip.org/#intro and was looking at it and tried to convert a javascript  file which it just converted directly and changed the extension to gz.Can someone tell me how can we create a new file without modifying the original file using GZip command line and also is this GZip file the same which say a web server like IIS creates and sends to the client when compression is enabled.

I am thinking of GZipping all our JS and CSS and HTMl files before hand so the web server can directly render it .I know the web server by itself only renders these zip fles if the client supports but I m just trying some new stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on a *NIX machine, you can use

```
gzip -c FILE > FILE.gz
```

to write the gzipped data to a different file. The `-c` writes to stdout, and the `>` redirects stdout to a file. If you have many you could try a loop in Bash:

```
for file in *.js
do
    gzip -c "$file" > "${file}.gz"
done
```

Also, be really *really* certain your server falls back on the nongzipped versions if the client doesn't support it!